# Use of "get Stringify" and "get props" in dart

Tags: dart, stringify

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Point extends Equatable {
  const Point(this.x, this.y);
  final int x;
  final int y;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [x, y];

  @override
  bool? get stringify => true;

  Point operator +(Point other) {
    return Point(x + other.x, y + other.y);
  }

  Point operator *(int other) {
    return Point(x * other, y * other);
  }
}

void main() {
  print(Point(1, 1) == Point(1, 1));

  print(Point(2, 1));
}
```

What does "Stringify" and "get props" does is this block of code?
It is given that "If set to true, the [toString] method will be overridden to output this instance's [props]." regarding the use of Stringify. What does it mean by "this instance's [props]."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the `equatable` package are described as:

> A Dart package that helps to implement value based equality without needing to explicitly override `==` and `hashCode`.

To do achieve this goal, we can make our classes extend from `Equatable` (or use the `EquatableMixin` with `with`) which will then come with the implementation for `==` and `hashCode`.

But `Equatable` can't inspect the object at runtime to figure out what fields your class have defined. And `Equatable` does also not require a precompile step. Also, you might not want to compare all fields of your objects when determine that two objects are equal.

So the way `Equatable` understands what fields you want to have compared, is by using a `props` getter that you must define if using `Equatable`. This getter must then return a list of objects that should be compared when determining the equality of two objects.

Behind the scene, `Equatable` will call this `probs` getter whenever something calls `==` or `hashCode` on your object.

The purpose of the `stringify` getter is then to tell `Equatable` if it, besides `==` and `hashCode`, should also implement a `toString()` for your class. By default, the `toString()` method, in Dart, will just tell you the type of object you have like `Instance of 'Point'`.

If `stringify` returns `true`, then `Equatable` will use the returned value from `probs` to contruct its own `toString()` method which lists the value of each element in `probs` (which correspond to each field of your class).

It is just an extra optional service if you already want your `toString()` to list the value of each field of your class.